# How to cell fracture without internal volume, only on surface?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to take a mesh like this:

[image: Mesh]

And cell fracture it, but only to the surface of the mesh, so the pieces are planes instead of large fragments. My end goal is to produce an animation like this:
[image: Goal]

I managed to achieve this by splitting my mesh into separate planes. Then cell fracturing each plane individually. I'm wondering if there's a faster and less tedious way to do this. I got more complex models I want to apply this effect on and the way I'm doing this simply won't work on those models.

Anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Hi! For complex fracturing use "Fracture modifier" branch of Blender. As for default tools - "Explode" modifier can do something similar.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm currently using Blender 2.79 with Cell Fracture add-on enabled, is the fracture modifier you're referring to different? If so how do I access it? As for explode, there doesn't seem to much parameters to play around with to get the results I want. Am I missing some obvious button to expose more options?

Comment: Branches are unofficial builds, get them here for example: https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Kbbbbc/. I'm no expert in fracturing, but this branch is more precise and tweakable than default "Cell Fracture" add-on, it also provides "shell only" fracture. "Explode" is mainly controled by particle system, better watch some tutorials about it.

Comment: Ah got the build thanks! Don't see an obviously labeled option for shell only fracture though.. Ah well, time to go through a bunch of tutorials again haha.

Comment: In algorithm settings there are couple of choices w/o "fill" in the name, but contain "bisect"

Comment: Omg that's it! Thank you so much for all your help! Muchas gracias!